# Eclipse Start Up Issues

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create an **Eclipse Plugin** product, after the export process and all it produce an **.EXE** format eclipse window to the clients. When I try to open the eclipse (.exe), it produce an error like as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: How are you exporting the product? With a .product file?

Answer (score 0):

In your product plugin, open the manifest. Then check to make sure you have added all dependencies in the dependency tab. There is an option to add all required. Try this, it should help.